# how to capture internet file download file info in dot net

Tags: c#

hello i am developing an dot net application in C# and i want to get the file download information like name,size  etc 
so can any one tell me how i can do this ....Thank  you...

Comment: Need more information here ... are you developing a web application, or a windows application. What technology are you planning to use ASP.NET, ASP MVC, FTP, etc.

Comment: its a windows application i dont want much of UI but i need the data

Comment: So you're not developing a download manager? Is the user using your program to download the file? Or do you want to monitor what they download in IE? What about other browsers? Or are you writing a more general network activity monitor? What is the underlying problem you're actually trying to solve? By which, I don't mean technical. I mean social, user or policy problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use FileStream or like this not WebClient. You get file size with FileStream length method. If you want to learn file name you should parse url and get it.

I think you  try to develop app like this. It has also multithreading. Look at this project.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MyDownloader.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer i really dont want to develop download manager i need file info of the downloaded file as soon as user downloads a file i want the file name as well as size of the file can u please guide me futher

Comment: I developped a multithread download manager in past. But I don't remember the details. I must do a little search after it I guide you further bro